# Why does authenticated write to realtime database prevents writing without authentication in an openly writable firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My realtime database rules are

```
{
    ".read": "auth.uid == 'mySpecificUID'",
    ".write": "auth.uid == 'mySpecificUID'",
    "somedata": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

So it allows complete r/w to my account only.
EDITED:

I've made two web apps, App 1 requires authentication before writing data and App 2 needs no authentication.

App 1

```
<head>
    <title>Test App 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <!-- fb init code -->
    <script>
        let firebaseConfig = {
            // config values from CDN code
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        let database = firebase.database();
        console.log("Log: firebase initialised");
    </script>
    <!-- auth + write code -->
    <script>
        function auth(email, password) {
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
                let user = userCredential.user;
                console.log ("Log: uid = " + user.uid);
                // writing to db
                let input = prompt("Enter string");
                if (input == "" || input == null) {
                    console.error("Error: write(): Empty string entered");
                    return;
                }
                console.log ("Entered: " + input);
                try {
                    database.ref("/somedata/").set({
                        "data": {
                            "value1": input
                        }
                    })
                    .catch (error => {
                        console.error("Error: write(): " + error);
                    });
                    console.log ("Log: write(): write success");
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error: write(): " + error);
                }           
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error: auth(): " + error.message);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

App 2

```
<head>
    <title>Test App 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <!-- fb init code -->
    <script>
        let firebaseConfig = {
            // config values from CDN code
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        let database = firebase.database();
        console.log("Log: firebase initialised");
    </script>
    <!-- write code -->
    <script>
        function write() {
            let input = prompt("Enter string");
            if (input == "" || input == null) {
                console.error("Error: write(): Empty string entered");
                return;
            }
            console.log ("Entered: " + input);
            try {
                database.ref("/somedata/").set({
                    "data": {
                        "value2": input
                    }
                })
                .catch (error => {
                    console.error("Error: write(): " + error);
                });
                console.log ("Log: write(): write success");
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error("Error: write(): " + error);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

First I execute app 1, authenticate myself,  and write some data. It works.

But if I use app 2, data isn't written and no error message pops up.

Permission should not be denied as the rules allow anyone to write data to `somedata` (and it doesn't deny permission, as I mentioned previously, no error message pops up).

I've checked if data is getting written to any other database from app 2 but that's not the case.

You can execute the functions from the console.

Comment: What is the value of `path` in your code? Also: what is the value of `data`? Also: are you sure your app is talking this *this* project/database? If it is configured to connect to another project, that would explain the problem you're having.

Comment: ```path``` is ```"/targetData/"```. value of ```data``` from authenticated app was ```{"undefined": "default"}```. There's no special characters in it. From the 2nd app, I tried writing ```{"undefined": "defined"}```. Yes, I'm sure the app's connecting to this database. I've checked that (copy pasted the CDN codes and firebaseConfig values) multiple times when it stopped writing.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, so assume it's something we're not seeing here. Please edit your question to show the exact code we can run to reproduce the problem without any external dependencies. From your latest comment, you should also get the problem when you do `db.ref("/targetData/").update({"undefined": "default"})`. Please test that, and if it indeed gives the same problem, update the question to show the updated code.

Comment: Edited my question with the actual code